# Error loading renderer 'vscode.builtin-renderer'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running jupyter notebook in vs code for a long time without any problem. Recently, I got this below error. To solve it, I have close vs code, then re-open it and it is fine. Any suggestion to solve it without closing vs code? Thanks

```
Error loading renderer 'vscode.builtin-renderer'
Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/test/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/extensions/notebook-renderers/renderer-out/index.js
```